# why would std::vector max_size() function return -1?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a `std::vector<unsigned char> m_vData;`

`m_vData.max_size()` always returns -1.  why would that happen?

Comment: It'll return all sorts of funny things, if you assign the result to the wrong datatype. The function returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned. If you see a -1, you're converting it to another type, and then yes, you may lose or alter data. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably because you're assigning it to a signed type before viewing.  The return value of max_size is typically `size_t` which is an unsigned type.  A straight conversion to say int on many platforms would return -1.

Try the following instead

```
std::vector<unsigned char>::size_type v1 = myVector.max_size();
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that `max_size()` returns a `vector::size_type` which is unsigned, so you're seeing a negative number due to converting it somewhere (you're really getting a very large unsigned number back).

The implementation is saying that it could handle vectors with that many elements (though I doubt that you'd actually get one allocated).

It's not not the number of elements in the vector (or currently reserved for the vector).  You can get those numbers with `vector::size()` or `vector::capacity()`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that, on most platforms, `std::vector<unsigned char>::max_size` is quite likely to be the same as `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`, which of course is -1 when converted to a signed int.